# Copy String by Azure Data Factory Failed

Tags: azure, encoding, azure-data-factory

I am trying to do following...
With Azure Data Fatctory, pipeline copys string from JSON file in Blob Storage to Azure SQL.

I am facing problem as below...
Copied String to Azure SQL is displayed as "???" while original string is "圃場1"(ASC-II format)

How do I properly copy original string to Azure SQL?(Maybe, I need to setup encoding format within LinkedService file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the correct encoding in the input dataset of your pipeline. You can do this in the format property, with type TextFormat and encodingName. Read more about these properties here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#dataset-properties

Your linked service is working fine, as you can get data from your blob storage so no need to change that.

Your format json would look something like this:

```
"format": {
            "type": "TextFormat",
            "encodingName": "gb2312"
        }
```

In this example I used gb2312 because I think those characters are chinese, but I'm not really sure. You can check other encodings here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.encoding.aspx

Also reading this might be useful, to get to know a bit more about other text format properties: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#text-format

Hope this helped! :)

Comment: Thank you Martin.